# How to get key hashes for facebook for facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook

I making keyhashes using this command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to generate debug and release keyhash. However, pair of those keys works only when facebook app is not installed on device. If it is installed another pair of hashes is required (4 keys in total) and i don't anderstand how to get those 2 keys (I  am getting them when facebook sdk returns error message `xxxx key is not registered`)

Comment: When the FB App is installed you need to use release keyhash. After making the final release build if you get the same error simply copy the keyhash from the message on your phone and add to the console. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
        }
    }
```

This will generate debug key hash, if you want release key hash, select build variants in android studio and then change debug to release. Now again run the above method this will generate release key hash.